# Google spreadsheet function to generate a week number for a date column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Function to generate a week number for a date column in Google spreadsheet?

**Example:**

```
date - week
2021-01-01 0:00:00 - 
2021-01-04 0:00:00 - 2
2021-01-05 0:00:00 - 2
2021-01-10 0:00:00 - 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [WEEKNUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949?hl=en) function for this!

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are in col A, put this in cell B1:

`=arrayformula({"week";if(A2:A<>"",weeknum(A2:A,2),)})`

`ARRAYFORMULA` from cell B1 works down the sheet.

`"week"` puts the title (week) in cell B1, then the `;` returns the line.

If A is not empty then calculate the week number `weeknum(A2:A,2)`. If A is empty, then nothing.

The `,2` in `weeknum` has the week starting on Monday, ending Sunday. It looks like your example is working on Sunday to Saturday, which will need `,1` (or omitted) instead.

If you want Col B to be like your example above, you can Add A to the calc and format it using `text`:

`=arrayformula({"date - week";if(A2:A<>"",text(A2:A,"yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss")&" - "&weeknum(A2:A,1),)})`